# Dell Wireless 375 Bluetooth Drivers for Latitude E6510. Win 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, headphones, dell-latitude

I need working drivers for Dell Wireless 375 Bluetooth Drivers for Latitude E6510 on Win 7 x64, so I can connect my bluetooth headphones.

On Windows 8 and 10 when I do fresh installation stock drivers are good and everything works fine. 
But in Windows 7 stock drivers and also drivers v.6.3.0.3102, A02, v.6.3.0.7900, A05 & A04 v. 6.3.0.6900 don't offer any functionality for my bluetooth headphones and for my phone. Problem is that I can't work on WIN 8 or 10 because notebook isn't stable on these OS.

My device ID is:

```
USB\VID_413C&PID_8187&REV_0517

USB\VID_413C&PID_8187
```

I tried to transfer drivers from WIN 8 & 10, but with no luck.

Comment: what is not stable in Windows 8/10? Which issues do you have?

Comment: I only found 1 driver for the 375 bluetooth on the Dell Site for your specific model? There is also a bluetooth application software, not sure what that is.

Comment: magicandre1981/
Not exactly unstable. Last last year I installed Win8.1 and few months after that my LCD stopped working, and I had to buy new one. Since drivers on Dell page go up to Win7, now I am afraid to install 8.1 or 10. Maybe it is just coincidence or maybe graphic drivers have something with it./

Moab/
I installed every driver from Dell site (vista x64 x86, 7 x64, x86) but no luck.

Comment: a broken LCD has nothing to do with a Windows version. Install Win8.1 again if this worked

Comment: @magicandre1981 
i don't know. i am very afraid for that could make my lcd stop working. obviously you know much, but you cant blame me for fear. can graphic driver or any other make a mess? maybe giving wrong set of instructions or commands to hardware?

Comment: in this case you have to live with the broken Bluetooth functionality